# Spring Security WebFlux - "AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: Not Authenticated" with custom AuthenticationEntryPoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid, external, spring-webflux

I'm trying to configure a Spring Security within a reactive Spring Boot application with a Vuejs frontend that redirect users to an external OpenID provider (for authentication) when unauthenticated. After users are authenticated with the OpenID provider and redirect back to the application (frontend), an UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (Authentication) will be created based on the response of the OpenID provider and be manually authenticated.

However, when doing so, the application seems to be unable to detect that the user have been authenticated as the AuthenticationEntryPoint is still invoke with the following exception and the preAuthenticationFilter (shown later) still being called repeatedly due to not being authenticated.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: Not Authenticated
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.commenceAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.lambda$filter$1(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$25(Mono.java:3146)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1748)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1748)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:181)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3852)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:98)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:77)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:275)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:849)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:166)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:141)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.subscribe(MonoProcessor.java:457)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:113)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2071)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:185)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterFuseable.subscribe(MonoFilterFuseable.java:47)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterFuseable.subscribe(MonoFilterFuseable.java:47)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefaultIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoDefaultIfEmpty.java:37)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:113)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2071)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:185)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterFuseable.subscribe(MonoFilterFuseable.java:47)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3852)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:442)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:212)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefaultIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoDefaultIfEmpty.java:37)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilter.subscribe(MonoFilter.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3852)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3852)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:78)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2073)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1879)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1753)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3852)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:794)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:560)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:540)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:265)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:201)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:335)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter.subscribe(FluxFilter.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilter.subscribe(MonoFilter.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:262)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1516)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.subscribe(MonoProcessor.java:457)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilter.subscribe(MonoFilter.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefaultIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoDefaultIfEmpty.java:37)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3852)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3852)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:141)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:113)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2071)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:185)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterFuseable.subscribe(MonoFilterFuseable.java:47)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscriberContext.subscribe(MonoSubscriberContext.java:47)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscriberContext.subscribe(MonoSubscriberContext.java:47)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:333)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollectList.java:72)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:295)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterWhen.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:243)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:201)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen.subscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:69)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3852)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:70)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:64)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:226)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:442)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:91)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:161)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:302)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:697)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$1(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    ... 214 more
```

So far, I have managed to redirect users to the external OpenID provider for authentication by utilizing the following AuthenticationEntryPoint. And also being able to be redirected back to the frontend if the user is able to login to the OpenID provider.

```
@Component
public class OpenIDAuthenticationEntryPoint implements ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {
  @Autowired
  private OpenIdUtil openIdUtil;

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> commence(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, AuthenticationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return openIdUtil.authRequest(serverWebExchange); // invoke openid function
  }
}
```

The OpenIdUtil class (with reference from openid4java's SampleConsumer)

```
Log4j2
@Service
public class OpenIdUtil {
  private ConsumerManager manager;

  public OpenIdUtil() {
    // instantiate a ConsumerManager object
    manager = new ConsumerManager();
  }

  /**  placing the authentication request  **/
  public Mono<Void> authRequest(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
    System.out.println("AUTH-REQUEST");
    try
    {
      // configure the return_to URL where your application will receive the authentication responses from the OpenID provider
      String returnToUrl = "<return url>"; 

      // perform discovery on the user-supplied identifier
      List discoveries = manager.discover("<the url of the external openid provider>");

      // attempt to associate with the OpenID provider and retrieve one service endpoint for authentication
      DiscoveryInformation discovered = manager.associate(discoveries);

      // store the discovery information in the user's session
      serverWebExchange.getSession().map(session -> {
        session.getAttributes().put("openid-disc", discovered);
        return session;
      }).subscribe();

      // obtain a AuthRequest message to be sent to the OpenID provider
      AuthRequest authReq = manager.authenticate(discovered, returnToUrl);

      serverWebExchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
      serverWebExchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create(authReq.getDestinationUrl(true)));
      return serverWebExchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }
    catch (OpenIDException e)
    {
      // present error to the user
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  /** processing the authentication response **/
  String verifyResponse(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {

    try
    {
      // extract the parameters from the authentication response (which comes in as a HTTP request from the OpenID provider)
      MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getQueryParams();
      ParameterList response = new ParameterList(queryParams.toSingleValueMap());

      // retrieve the previously stored discovery information
      final DiscoveryInformation[] discovered = new DiscoveryInformation[1];
      serverWebExchange.getSession().map(session -> discovered[0] = session.getAttribute("openid-disc")).subscribe();

      // extract the receiving URL from the HTTP request
      String receivingURL = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getURI().toString();
      // verify the response; ConsumerManager needs to be the same (static) instance used to place the authentication request
      VerificationResult verification = manager.verify(receivingURL, response, discovered[0]);

      // examine the verification result and extract the verified identifier
      Identifier verified = verification.getVerifiedId();

      if (verified != null)
      {
        return verified.getIdentifier();  // success
      }
    }
    catch (OpenIDException e)
    {
      // present error to the user
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }

}
```

I have also created a custom ReactiveAuthenticationManager to manually perform "authentication" (referencing a Spring webflux JWT example - https://github.com/heesuk-ahn/spring-webflux-jwt-auth-example)

```
@Component
public class OpenIDReactiveAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {
  @Override
  public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    return Mono.just(authentication);
  }
}
```

And a ServerAuthenticationConverter to validates OpenId authentication response coming from AuthenticationFilter ServerWebExchange.

```
@Component
public class PreAuthenticationConverter implements ServerAuthenticationConverter {

  @Autowired
  private OpenIdUtil openIdUtil;

  @Override
  public Mono<Authentication> convert(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
    try {
      String user = URI.create(openIdUtil.verifyResponse(serverWebExchange)).getPath();
      // extract credentials here
      if (!user.isEmpty()){
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        updatedAuthorities.add(authority);
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,null, updatedAuthorities);

        return Mono.just(authentication);
      }
      return Mono.empty();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // log error here
      return Mono.empty();
    }
  }
}
```

And lastly the SecurityConfiguration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private PreAuthenticationConverter preAuthenticationConverter;

  @Autowired
  private OpenIDAuthenticationEntryPoint openIDAuthenticationEntryPoint;

  @Autowired
  private OpenIDReactiveAuthenticationManager openIDReactiveAuthenticationManager;

  SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChainStg(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/actuator/health", "/actuator/info").permitAll()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterAt(preAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(openIDAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("authorization");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("content-type");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }

  private AuthenticationWebFilter preAuthenticationFilter(){
    AuthenticationWebFilter preAuthenticationFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(openIDReactiveAuthenticationManager);
    preAuthenticationFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(preAuthenticationConverter);
    return preAuthenticationFilter;
  }
}
```

I have tried various method such as manually setting the Authentication into the WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository but still did not manage to authenticate the user as the AuthenticationEntryPoint keep getting invoke for each request coming from the frontend.

```
ServerSecurityContextRepository serverSecurityContextRepository = new WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository();
    return serverSecurityContextRepository.save(exchange,
        new SecurityContextImpl(authentication))
        .subscriberContext(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication));
```

Hoping someone can give some insights/guides to why the authentication is deemed to be not "authenticated" instead of the expected outcome where user will be able to access the frontend without being repeatedly redirect back and forth the frontend and OpenID provider by the AuthenticationEntryPoint

Comment: i think you need to read up on how oauth2 flows first work in spring, and then after you know that see how OpenId is used in oauth2 flows in spring. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-user-service also you are coding imperative while using webflux, you should not `subscribe` in your application

Comment: i also strongly suggest you take 30 mins to read the technical overview of https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#technical-overview so you know what the UserDetailsService does, what the authenticationManager does, what filters there are, and how you configure oauth2 flows, so you dont write your own custom filters.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Thanks, I have read the documentations, but do correct me if i'm wrong as I'm fairly new to spring webflux. The OpenID in oauth2 flows is referring to the OIDC not OpenID 2.0 protocol that I'm integrating. As such, this is the reason why i'm creating a custom filter that would authenticate the Authenticate creating using:
```Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,null, updatedAuthorities);

```
Also, from my understanding, on authentication success by the custom reactive authentication manager, the context should be set automatically.

Comment: i can see you are fairly new to spring webflux because you dont write reactive code like this `serverWebExchange.getSession().map(session -> { session.getAttributes().put("openid-disc", discovered); return session; }).subscribe();` and you dont use try catch in reactive programming because try catch destroys the event chain. Then i also suggest you to read the basic principals of reactive programming https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive

Comment: think of reactive program as a series of callbacks, or a conveyer belt with different transforms along the way. The subscriber is the calling client, the webpage, when the client subscribes it triggers your event chain (conveyer belt) to start performing.

you should hardly never subscribe in your own application. There is always a publisher (your service) and a subscriber (the calling client)

Comment: learn how to use `Mono<T>` and or `Flux<T>` first, how to transform data, pass through data etc. etc. first then apply that knowledge to your code. Right now you are mixing imperative programming and reactive programming which is not good. And when you are mixing it, anything can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to know what is wrong because i can't run your code and you are mixing imperative programming with reactive programming.

There are several issues with your code that i have pointed out in the comments below your original question.

Im going to try to explain what is wrong more specifically

```
public Mono<Void> authRequest(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {

    // Here we are in the imperative world and everything is fine, we get some 
    // stuff and set some parameters.
    System.out.println("AUTH-REQUEST");
    String returnToUrl = "..."; 
    List discoveries = manager.discover( ... );
    DiscoveryInformation discovered = manager.associate(discoveries);

    // Here we now jump into the reactive world, and we start working with Monos. 
    // This means that we have to start chaining things, because we are going to 
    // declare what we want our service to do when we eventually get data in our 
    // Mono.
    return serverWebExchange.getSession()
        .map(session -> {

            AuthRequest authReq = manager.authenticate(discovered, returnToUrl);
            serverWebExchange.getResponse()
                .setStatusCode(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
            serverWebExchange.getResponse()
                .getHeaders()
                .setLocation(URI.create(authReq.getDestinationUrl(true)));      

            session.getAttributes().put("openid-disc", discovered);
        return serverWebExchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    })
}
```

I hope you understand the concept more clearly with this example.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use this as a starting point to understand and also change the codes to reactive programming. I'll update the post once i have updated the codes and test if the code works.